# Erro de execução em c

Tags: c, alocação, malloc

Estou com um problema no seguinte código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **tabela_hash;
int valorTotal=0;

void inicializarTabela(int *pm)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (*pm); i++){
        tabela_hash[i] = malloc(50*sizeof(char));
    }
}
int acharPosicaoAlfabeto(char *c)
{
    int asc;
    asc = *c;
    return (asc-65);
}

int calculoHash(char *c, int *i, int *j)
{   
    int posicaoAlfabeto;
    int elementoEntrada;
    int posicaoElemento;
    int valor;
    posicaoAlfabeto = acharPosicaoAlfabeto(c);
    posicaoElemento = *i;
    elementoEntrada = *j;
    valor = elementoEntrada + posicaoAlfabeto + posicaoElemento; 
    valorTotal = valorTotal + valor;
    return valorTotal;
}

void lerString(int *pqtdLinhas)
{   
    int valorHash;
    for (int j=0; j < (*pqtdLinhas); j++){
        scanf("%50s",tabela_hash[j]);
        int i = 0;
        while (tabela_hash[j][i] != '\0' &&  i < 50){
            valorHash = calculoHash(&tabela_hash[j][i], &i, &j);
            i++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",valorHash);
    valorTotal=0;
}

int main()
{
    int qtdTestes, *pqtdTestes = &qtdTestes;
    scanf("%d",pqtdTestes);
  
    int qtdLinhas, *pqtdLinhas = &qtdLinhas;
    scanf("%d",pqtdLinhas);

    tabela_hash = (char **) malloc ((*pqtdLinhas) * sizeof(char*));
    inicializarTabela(pqtdLinhas);
    lerString(pqtdLinhas);

    int i=1;
    while (*pqtdTestes > 1 && i < *pqtdTestes){
        scanf("%d",pqtdLinhas);
        tabela_hash = (char **) realloc(tabela_hash, (*pqtdLinhas) * sizeof(char*));
        inicializarTabela(pqtdLinhas);
        lerString(pqtdLinhas);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Explicação rápida do que ele faz: eu crio uma matriz tabela_hash e cada elemento dela é um ponteiro para um vetor de char, ou seja uma string. Em cada string, eu preciso ler caracter por caracter para fazer um calculo do valor de cada um, e no final eu imprimo o valor total acumulado da matriz. Como pode existir mais de um caso de teste, eu realoco espaço para tabela_hash e faço todas as operações novamente.

A questão é a seguinte: ja testei esse código em varias IDE's e ele funciona. Porém, como ele faz parte de uma atividade, preciso enviar ele através do juiz online Thehuxley, e lá na hora de executar ele dá um erro "Erro de execução". Ja revisei todo meu código e não sei onde poderia está esse erro, apesar de suspeitar das funções malloc e realloc. Se alguém puder me ajudar a encontrá-lo ficarei grato.

Edit: Abaixo, segue uma outra versão do código trabalhando tabela_hash como um vetor, ao invés de matriz, como ocorre no primeiro código. Essa segunda versão também funciona, porém o erro de execução que ela gera é exatamente esse: "realloc(): invalid next size". Preciso de uma solução pra qualquer uma das versões. Mas como esse segundo código gera um erro específico, talvez seja mais fácil de encontrar uma solução.

Versão 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *tabela_hash;
int valorTotal = 0;


int acharPosicaoAlfabeto(char *c)
{
    int asc;
    asc = *c;
    return (asc-65);
}

int calculoHash(char *c, int *i, int *j)
{   
    int posicaoAlfabeto;
    int elementoEntrada;
    int posicaoElemento;
    int valor;
    posicaoAlfabeto = acharPosicaoAlfabeto(c);
    posicaoElemento = *i;
    elementoEntrada = *j;
    valor = elementoEntrada + posicaoAlfabeto + posicaoElemento; 
    valorTotal = valorTotal + valor;
    return valorTotal;
}

void lerString(int *pqtdLinhas)
{   
    int valor;
    for (int j=0; j < (*pqtdLinhas); j++){
        scanf("%51s",tabela_hash);
        int i = 0;
        while (tabela_hash[i] != '\0' &&  i < 50){
            valor = calculoHash(&tabela_hash[i], &i, &j);
            i++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",valor);
    valorTotal=0;
}

int main()
{
    int qtdTestes, *pqtdTestes = &qtdTestes;
    scanf("%d",pqtdTestes);
  
    int qtdLinhas, *pqtdLinhas = &qtdLinhas;
    scanf("%d",pqtdLinhas);

    tabela_hash = (char *) malloc ((*pqtdLinhas) * sizeof(char));
    lerString(pqtdLinhas);

    int i=1;
    while (*pqtdTestes > 1 && i < *pqtdTestes){
        scanf("%d",pqtdLinhas);
        tabela_hash = (char *) realloc (tabela_hash, (*pqtdLinhas) * sizeof(char));
        lerString(pqtdLinhas);  
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Exemplo de entrada:

```
5 -> corresponde a 5 casos de teste
2 -> corresponde a 2 linhas
CBA -> string de entrada da linha 1
DDD -> string de entrada da linha 2
1 -> corresponde a uma linha dos mesmos 5 casos de teste citado acima
Z -> string desta linha acima
6 -> corresponde a 6 linhas dos mesmos 5 casos de teste citado acima
A -> string da linha 1 destas 6 linhas citada aqui acima
B -> string da linha 2 destas 6 linhas citada aqui acima
C -> string da linha 3 destas 6 linhas citada aqui acima
D -> string da linha 4 destas 6 linhas citada aqui acima
E -> string da linha 5 destas 6 linhas citada aqui acima
F -> string da linha 6 destas 6 linhas citada aqui acima
6 -> mais 6 linhas abaixo:
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
1 -> uma linha abaixo:
ZZZZZZZZZZ
```

Totalizando 5 casos de teste acima.

O resultado esperado é:

```
21
25
30
4290
295
```

Comment: Experimente usar `_malloca(size_t size)` (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/malloca?view=msvc-160). Espero que ajude!

Comment: Tentei aqui, mas no thehuxley não deu certo pq essa função _malloca é do windows, correto? Ele não reconhece, mesmo eu importando windows.h e malloc.h